# UTF-8 issue with Soft Hyphen (U+00AD) in both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTex

Tags: unicode, utf8

I have a very simple test case that displays all of the Latin-1 printable characters (`U+0021` - `U+007e`, `U+00A1` - `U+00ff`). It works correctly for every UTF-8 character except `U+00AD`. It fails with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTex.

It does not matter if I use `unicode-math`, nor does it matter if I set the monospace font. If I open the source file in Notepad, everything displays correctly, no matter which font I choose (as long as Latin-1 is supported by the font). If I do set a font using setmonofont it doesn't make any difference.

Here is the test case:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . /
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ?
@ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O
P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _
` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o
p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~

¡ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © ª « ¬ ­ ® ¯
° ± ² ³ ´ µ ¶ · ¸ ¹ º » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿
À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï
Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß
à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï
ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

This does not show correctly in the question, so an image of the source is also included in a monospace font.

[image: Sample Test Code]

And here is the output. It can be seen that on the first line above the ASCII range (starting with the inverted !) that following the "not" symbol, the hyphen is omitted. This may be correct in non-verbatim mode, since it is a "weak" hyphen if it were embedded in a word. However, that processing should not occur in verbatim mode. Note that it also fails when not in verbatim mode, and since the weak hyphen is not embedded in a word, it should not be omitted (as Notepad shows).

[image: Test Output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever Notepad shows should not be taken as an absolute rule. For instance, the editors I have on my machine don't show U+00AD.

[image]

Not even if I ask to show invisible characters

[image]

However, you might decide to show the character inside `verbatim` and it's not difficult: hook into the code to add your personal stuff when initiating `verbatim`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@verbatim}{\@noligs}{\@noligs\@otherstuff}{}{}
\def\@otherstuff{\catcode"AD=\active}
\begingroup
\catcode"AD=\active
\gdef^^ad{{\ooalign{-\cr\hidewidth?\hidewidth\cr}}}
\endgroup


\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
  ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . /
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ?
@ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O
P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _
` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o
p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~

  ¡ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © ª « ¬ ­ ® ¯
° ± ² ³ ´ µ ¶ · ¸ ¹ º » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿
À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï
Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß
à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï
ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Decide about the appearance, here a question mark superimposed to a hyphen.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior. Notepad might be showing you the character as a hyphen, but my editor for one does not: It displays `<0xad>` to denote an unprintable character.

You see, back in 2002 when Unicode 4.0 first came out, the category of `U+00AD` SOFT HYPHEN was changed from the previous "Pd" (punctuation, dash) to "Cf" (other, format), following HTML 4.0's lead, where `&shy;` has always behaved that way.

This means that the sole purpose of this character is to mark an *invisible hyphenation opportunity*, which only becomes a visible hyphen at the end of a line after formatting, if and when needed. Really just like `\-` in TeX, all things considered.

[image]

Comment: I would agree, except that the character is inside a verbatim environment, which is intended to display its contents exactly as they are. Also, Word 2016 displays the character. I believe that, in isolation, or in the verbatim environment, that the character should be displayed.

Comment: I disagree, as there is simply no character to display here. How do you “print“ a format character, anyway? 

By my latest count, Unicode knows 161 “formatting” characters. `SOFT HYPHEN` is the only one to be included in the `LATIN-1 SUPPLEMENT` block, but the `BASIC MULTILINGUAL PLANE` has many more: There's `ZERO WIDTH JOINER (U+200D)` and `RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK (U+200F)` and 159 more – none of which will print because they are, by definition, unprintable.

Not exactly a new issue, either. ASCII always had (unprintable) control characters like `NUL (U+0000)`, `ALERT (U+0007)` etc.

Comment: First, there certainly is a character to be printed. If it used, as intended, in text as soft hyphenation, and the containing word breaks at that point, then it will be displayed. Second, in verbatim mode, printable characters are to be displayed without invoking editing or formatting. Otherwise, you cannot actually see what is there. Third, it is not a control character, of which there are 65 in Latin-1, it is a printable character that may be suppressed when hyphenating a word. Outside of that use, it is still printable.

Comment: No, there is no character to be printed here. According to the Unicode specs it's “an **invisible** *format* character indicating a possible hyphenation location” (my emphasis). Note how it doesn't say *control* character, although the difference doesn't really matter much in this context. I have amended my answer to include a screenshot from the Unicode website, showing the details (Note the dashed bounding box used for unprintable characters). That said, I really have zero interest in discussing this any further.  What you are experiencing is documented and expected behavior. Deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression can find formatting characters and replace them with something visible:

[image: visible now]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \showAD } { +m } {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { \xAD } 
                { \cB\{ \c{color} \cB\{ red \cE\} A \cE\} \c{llap}\cB\{ D \cE\} } 
                \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}
                        
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

abc­xyz (invisible)

\showAD{abc­xyz} (visible)

\ttfamily
\showAD{¡ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © ª « ¬ ­ ® ¯}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm totally gonna bookmark this for later use … Thanks :)

Comment: Certainly I could have used a regex to find and replace instances of U+00AD with U+002D, but I knew exactly where the character was located. I inserted it by hand, in hex, as I all of the other characters. I did not want to replace it, I wanted it to be displayed in the verbatim environment. I accepted the work-around to "tweak" the verbatim environment (slightly modified), but I still think that the verbatim environment should not perform any processing on the characters. Simply due to its entire reason for existing -- that of displaying source code.

Comment: @MichaelLeeFinney May be X-Y. If the chracter is for control, not display, how will *any* environment display it without tweaking/processing? This character, between the brackets,  >‍<, displays as invisible on my setup. So verbatim doing "no processing" and displaying nothing would be the desired behaviour, correct? Now, *marking* the character (by a space, say; or by nothing in a grid; or by < and >) is different, but that counts as a type of processing, doesn't it?

Comment: @MichaelLeeFinney You may be thinking verbatim is like a hex dump, perhaps. Verbatim doesn't tokenize, true, but it also just follows the font. (was designed especially to keep whitespace: space, tab, EOL, etc - all of which turn into glue when tokenized).

Comment: For controls, spaces, etc. you are correct. In the case of U+AD, it is a soft hyphen and may or may not display depending on if it is chosen as a hyphenation point. When in isolation, and especially when in verbatim mode, then it should display. If you are looking at source text, how will you know that you have a soft hyphen in the text unless you can see it being displayed? The only other choice is literally a hex dump, which is not what most people want to see. There must be some mode where the soft hyphen always displays, and for LaTeX, I believe that mode is the verbatim environment.

Comment: @MichaelLeeFinney And the ZWJ and ZWNJ? Unrelated: Alt-X (on Windows) does inspection (and status bar on the editor), and there are fonts that display all these otherwise undisplayable characters. Environments just use the font they are given.

Comment: As the author of the logix and logixMono fonts (available from CTAN), I can assure you that it is not the choice of the font. The font simply provides the glyph. How it is displayed is up to the client code. That is why the behavior of U+00AD did not change with respect to fonts.

Comment: @MichaelLeeFinney Yes, client code is what I intended to mean (poor choice of phrase; 1am is too late at night!). My questions revolve around: How would I code verbatim to identify a non-printable character. That is what I meant by the ZWJ/ZWNJ. As far as I can see, 2D will print, on AD's instrctions, but what will/can AD ever show (of itself)?

Comment: If I understood your question as to how you could write verbatim to know whether or not a character is printable, then there are essentially two ways: hard coded exceptions or a table of Unicode properties. I haven't looked at verbatim, but I would expect a table of properties. Because the Unicode Consortium might change those, add others or even remove some, and a table is the best way to ensure painless updates. As I mentioned before, that information is not contained in the font. The font only contains instructions for drawing glyphs, kerning for spacing and data for stretchy glyphs.

Comment: As far as what AD can display, the answer is exactly what the font defines for the glyph. It is just a glyph like any other. In my fonts, AD and 2D are identical (at least with the current unreleased version 12, with version 11 AD was slightly different, but still a dash). The only question is if it is to be displayed and if it is to be treated as a hyphenation break point. It is clear that if it is embedded in a word and the client is doing hyphenation that it will be displayed based on that. Otherwise, it can either be ignored as verbatim does by default or displayed as Notepad does.